# General user session handling (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

I wrote a simple webserver with `nodejs` and `express`. I implemented an user authentication with email username and password. Furthermore I have a remember-function which stores the user id and pwd hash into a cookie. Now I would like an extra session that ends when the user will close his browser or click to the logout button.

Which way is the best practice for implementation? Is the session the same like the remember-function with an expire time and in each request I must check the credentials against the database? (I'm not that sure about this)

Technologies that I'm using: `nodejs`, `express`, `mongodb`

This is not a `nodejs` question only, I would prefer a general explanation for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let me get this out of the way first; Storing the password hash into a cookie would allow anyone to login when they have the password hash and that would be disastrous if the password hashes ever got exposed for some reason. Encrypting cookies is just fine, but don't allow the actual hash you store in the database to be used for authentication. Ever.

About re-authentication, Node is a technology that operates on a single thread and is scaled by running more instances over multiple processors and/or machines. Keeping sessions is a good idea to avoid trips to the database, but you have to think about the architecture as well. What happens if you, say, use sessions stored in files (ala PHP) and you need to scale to multiple machines? Nothing good, at least. So you need a central point to keep track of the sessions.

This can be either your database (MongoDB) or something such as Redis, or another centralized mechanism allowing you to check sessions. Either way, you will have to spend time doing the request and retrieving the session values for the client. If you do not have additional values you need to store it makes no sense to create a dedicated session architecture (that needs expiration, and so forth) and just doing the authentication again is the easiest and most logical solution.

Personally I almost never need sessions and just do authentication again.